# github action cannot use action from private repo

Tags: github, github-actions

I have a paid github org.

We have a series of private repos - and along with that we need to use actions which are also held in private repos.

here is a simple example:

```
name: FE Main - Commit received
on:
  - push

jobs:
  deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: org-com/ghaction-slack-notification@v1
        with:
          slack_webhook_url: ${{ secrets.SLACK_WEBHOOK_URL }}
        if: always()
```

The action is using the action from within the org, however unless i make:

> org-com/ghaction-slack-notification

public.. then the actions fail as the tar cannot be loaded due to permissions.

The error is something like:

```
An action could not be found at the URI 'https://api.github.com/repos/org-com/ghaction-slack-notification/tarball/a5e91154adf6c4b628576352f8788ae4c203c02b'
```

How can i run an action that uses an action in private repo?

Comment: See [this issue about it](https://github.com/actions/checkout/issues/95). It is [already planned](https://github.com/github/roadmap/issues/74) and [there is a third-party-action for this](https://github.com/bagbyte/use-private-action).

Answer (score 1):

The documentation seems to suggest this is possible for internal repositories of GitHub Enterprise Cloud for organizations, [Allowing access to components in an internal repository](https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/managing-your-repositorys-settings-and-features/enabling-features-for-your-repository/managing-github-actions-settings-for-a-repository#allowing-access-to-components-in-an-internal-repository). Though I continue to receive the same error. Also, the issue, [Use actions from internal repositories](https://github.com/github/roadmap/issues/74), is planned for Q4 of 2021.

Answer (score -1):

It looks like GitHub actions for private repo's [isn't made available yet](https://github.community/t/github-action-action-in-private-repository/16063/57) :'(

Hopefully it will be sometime this year!

P.S. I've also tried to run GitHub actions in my private repo, but I"m getting this error: `Workflows can't be executed on this repository. Please check your payment method or billing status.`